# Get a part of attribute value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So basically i'm just trying to simplify this:

```
$('iframe[src*="foo"],iframe[src*="bar"]');
```

to something like:

```
var sources = ['foo', 'bar','something'];

$('iframe[src*="some string in array"]');
```

Hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the variable into the selector, like this:

```
var sources = ['foo', 'bar','something'];
$('iframe[src*="' + sources[0] + '"]');
```

See below for an example with images.  The ones with red borders are selected as part of the array

```js
var arr = ["http://placebear", "http://lorempixel", "http://placehold", "http://loremflickr"];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var $img = $('img[src*="'+arr[i]+'"]');
  
  $img.addClass('inarray');
  console.log($img);
}
```

```css
img {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
img.inarray {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placebear.com/200/200" />
<img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" />
<img src="http://loremflickr.com/200/200" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i was trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

var sources = ['foo', 'bar','something'];

$('iframe[src*="'+sources[Math.floor(Math.random()*sources.length)]+'"]');

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code and consider adding some short explanation.